# git .gitignore not ignoring previously tracked files

Tags: android, git, gitignore

I have an Android studio project (imported from eclipse). After I did the import to Andorid studio I did an initial commit and forgot to add the new .gitignore file for Android Studio's structure.

Now git won't ignore the build, .gradle files etc.

I have tried the

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "fixed untracked files"
```

trick but still when I write git status all files appear as deleted and in github they appear as changed.

Below is my .gitignore

```
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
.DS_Store

# Created by http://gitignore.io

### Android ###
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project    

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Proguard folder generated by Intellij
proguard_logs/

# Intellij project files
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

adt-bundle-windows-x86_64/

### Linux ###
.*
!.gitignore
!.git*
*~


### IntelliJ ###
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

### Gradle ###
# Exclude Folder List #
.gradle/
build/

/*/out
/*/*/build
/*/*/production
*.iws
*.ipr
*~
*.swp
```

I can still see all files in my build and .gradle folders etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: >I can still see all files in my build and .gradle folders etc.
I can't understand the question completely. If you don't want to see files - just delete them (not just from cache):
git rm -r --cached .

Also, have you tried make git clean -df  ? :-)

Comment: I tried git clean -df. 

What I mean is that:  I did the rm command, and now that the .gitignore is in place I would expect that in git status they would not appear again, but they do... And github's app shows them again

Comment: Sorry. You can just use `git clean -xf` as I described below :-) Hope It'll help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `git rm --cached "xxx"`
2. `git commit -m ""`
3. `git reset HEAD -- "xxx"`
4. `git commit -m ""` (to update repo)

Answer (score 7):

`git clean -xf` removes all files that matches .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you need to use this syntax:

`**/build`