# Gitignore not ignoring some build files in Android library

Tags: android, git, github, gitignore

I have [an Android library](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/UsefulViews) and for some reason, the files and folders I have specified in my `.gitignore` are not being ignored.

I have tried modifying my `.gitignore` and also following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33713937/4230345), but this doesn't change anything.

Here is my top-level `.gitignore` (which can also be found [on the GitHub repo](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/UsefulViews/blob/master/.gitignore)):

```
# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/
*/build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# IntelliJ
*.iml
/.idea
```

The [module with the `build` folder that isn't being ignored](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/UsefulViews/tree/master/library) has the following [`.gitignore`](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/UsefulViews/blob/master/library/.gitignore):

```
/build/
```

I'm not sure why the `build` directory isn't being ignored, as it is being ignored in my [sample app module](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/UsefulViews/tree/master/sample), and in the [top-level directory](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/UsefulViews).

Also, I did commit changes to some files in the `build` directory when I updated versions of my library, if that's important.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1139797/3187439

Comment: I just download .gitignore plugin to studio and being sure ignoring is done well

Comment: Thanks, @daco , your comment helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository/1139797#1139797) on Stack Overflow helped me solve my issue.

Here is part of that answer:

> **First commit any outstanding code changes**, and then, run this command:
>
> `git rm -r --cached .`
>
> This removes any changed files from the *index*(staging area), then just run:
>
> `git add .`
>
> Commit it:
>
> `git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"`

Answer (score 3):

You must remove the first `/` in your  lower level gitignore before build, it will work then. 
Also, in top level, you only need this: `build/` and then no lower level gitignore will be needed.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped, but it did not fix my issue. I found a fix to my problem though.

Comment: @farbodSalamat-Zadeh would you mind share the solution?

Comment: @Surt See my answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Add .gitignore file in your project, and set below lines:

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/libraries
/.idea/modules.xml
/.idea/workspace.xml
/build
/captures
.externalNativeBuild
.idea
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case the **.gitignore** file was placed inside **app** directory instead of being in **root of project** directory.

I figured this out by:

1. Open Project View in Android Studio
2. Right-click on build folder
3. Select Git
4. Add to .gitignore